# Eclipse Ganymede throws null pointer exception

Tags: eclipse, nullpointerexception, ganymede

my eclipse IDE throws a null pointer exception from time to time on a very regular basis (every 3-4 days). First my Java EE project(s) will not compile and will output a nullpointer exception in the errors tab.

I made sure that my project facet (java 5.0) and compiler are the same (1.5). However, when i restart Eclipse, the problem goes away after cleaning and rebuilding the projects - when there's no errors in the first place.

It gets annoying because it takes a long time for me to restart Eclipse IDE, clean+build, restart server and actually dev+test code.

I made sure I have plenty of memory too, 512 because I had a memory issue with Eclipse in the past as well but thats resolved. I mention it as it may be relevant.

I reintalled Eclipse Ganymede for Java EE 3 times in C:\Eclipse and still have the same problem too. Tried in D:\ another partitioned disk and doesnt work.

Advice will be greatly appreciated.

```
Eclipse Platform
Version: 3.4.2
Build id: M20090211-1700
Java EE Ganymede SR2 Win32
Platform: Windows XP 32-bit
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
!ENTRY com.bea.weblogic.eclipse 4 9999 2012-06-15 12:22:53.989
!MESSAGE Unhandled Eclipse-WebLogic error
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.bea.weblogic.eclipse.model.Deployments.getName(Deployments.java:292)
at com.bea.weblogic.eclipse.model.Deployments.loadEJBs(Deployments.java:237)
at com.bea.weblogic.eclipse.model.Deployments.loadAll(Deployments.java:109)
at com.bea.weblogic.eclipse.ui.views.WebLogicServerTreeContentProvider.loadModulesAndRefresh(WebLogicServerTreeContentProvider.java:273)
at com.bea.weblogic.eclipse.ui.views.WebLogicServerTreeContentProvider.serverStateChanged(WebLogicServerTreeContentProvider.java:247)
at com.bea.weblogic.eclipse.model.ServerManager.fireServerStateChanged(ServerManager.java:94)
at com.bea.weblogic.eclipse.launcher.ServerLauncher$3.run(ServerLauncher.java:199)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:133)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3800)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3425)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2384)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2348)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2200)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:495)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:288)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:490)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:193)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:386)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:549)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:504)
```

Comment: You can try a newer version, but at least reveal the exception's stack trace.

Comment: hi nitind, i managed to dig up the stack trace

Comment: Do you really use WebLogic integration plugin? Could you try to remove it?

Comment: yes i would think i need it as i run a weblogic server integrated with eclipse. so i run my server that way through the console tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some advices:

- You could try to run eclipse from console, configure some logging to understand exception. Maybe you should remove some plugin that you don't use.
- You could try to install just Eclipse Classic and after that install needed plugins. I do it always and haven't got any NPE exception issues. You'll get clean Eclipse without unnecessary plug-ins, so you reduce the possibility of exceptions.
- Also you could try to use new version of Eclipse - Indigo.
- You could also try to use some another IDE (for example: IntelliJ IDEA http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

It might be also interesting for you:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=328550
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321358
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326434